# How to deal: not a git repository: '/home/user/git' even if it is

Tags: bash, git

Some time ago i created a 'git' directory in a home path, just to store repos i use. But this somehow broke all my git system and even in ~ folder, when i was trying to use git, i was outputting me this (PWD=/home/user):

```
$ git status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

I've removed 'git' folder, but appear another problem (PWD=/home/user):

```
$ git status
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/user/git'
```

I tried to reinstall git. Not helped. I'm a bit confused about this.

---

**UPD #1:**
I'm sorry for bad explanation at the beginning.

This should be clear enough:

```
$pwd
/home/user/MyGitRepos/some_repo/

$ls -a
.  .. .git README.md

$git status
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/user/git'
```

Any path i am /, /etc, /home/user/ gives me the same output:

```
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/user/git'
```

Comment: Please stop changing your ground. It would be better to delete the question and not post it until you've figured out what the facts are and what you want to say.

Comment: @matt yeah i was not clear enough, when i posted the question at the first time. I've tried to describe too much. Now it's fine. Sorry for that, anyway

Comment: @matt you are not right saying that i'm changing ground. From the beginning i wrote that `git status` returns  "fatal: not a git repository: '/home/user/git'" even i was not in /home/user/git and FYTK first example i was at $HOME. It was not obvious enough. And that's why i'm sorry. But the ground is the same.

Comment: Sounds like you have `GIT_DIR` set in the environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-check your [environment variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_repository_locations).

If you have `GIT_DIR` or `GIT_WORK_TREE` set to `/home/user/git`, that would explain the error message.

Check also `git config -l --show-scope --show-origin` in case any configuration would also reference that path.